# Windows API CreateFile

Tags: c++, c, windows

Как мне узнать существует ли такой файл, которому обращается программа или он занят  другой программой?
CreateFile возвращает только -1.
В CreateFile я передаю OPEN_EXISTING.

Comment: может `GetLastError`  что-то полезное покажет?

Comment: Думал, что можно как то без этой функции, искать код ошибки не очень хотелось

Comment: код ошибки можно посмотреть в VS в меню lookup error

Answer (score 5):

Неужели так сложно [открыть MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)?

> **Return Value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the
>   specified file, device, named pipe, or mail slot.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. To
>   get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

Функция или возвращает handle указанного файла, или константу `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. В последнем случае используйте `GetLastError`

> dwCreationDisposition
>
> **OPEN_EXISTING**
>
> Opens a file or device, only if it exists.
>
> If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and
>   the last-error code is set to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2).

Если указан флаг `OPEN_EXISTING`, а файл не существует, то получим ошибку с кодом `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (как именно получить код ошибки см. выше)